# Filter choice column with distinct value in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, powerapp

I want to get distinct value in PowerApps where `Active (choice column)="Yes"`, trying below but I am not getting correct value it returns false value:

```
Distinct(Filter(Splist, Active =true),'spsinglelinetextcolumn')
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try it in below format:

```
Distinct(Filter(DataSource, Condition),ColumnToBeSelected)
```

**Source**: [Distinct values on a filtered drop down](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Distinct-values-on-a-filtered-drop-down/td-p/172598).

**Example**:

You have data source, `SPList` and a choice column (`Active`) with text value of `Yes`. Then you can use it something like below:

```
Distinct(Filter(SPList, Active = "Yes"), ColumnToBeSelected)
```

**official documentations**:

1. [Distinct function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct)
2. [Filter function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup)

Comment: It's the same formula in the question, what's the new in your answer?  How is it accepted? 

Comment: Are you serious? It's clear, the user don't need to know the formula syntax, he already knows it and the evidence is it is written in his question with the correct parameters , but his problem was in the condition logic! you didn't point him to this point, so you didn't add something new! It's not considered an answer to the question!  How is it accepted 

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I just needed to use `<>` instead of `=`.